# Get attribute of an object array as an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have created a class in python as below

```
class Member:
    def __init__(self, kalmanBoxTracker):
        self.member_id = kalmanBoxTracker.id
        self.member_area = kalmanBoxTracker.kf.x[2]
```

Then I have created an array of this object like this:

```
for trk in trackers:
   ret_mem.append(Member(trk))
```

How I can get the member_area attribute of ret_mem array as an array?

Comment: Try list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
member_areas = [m.member_area for m in ret_mem]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The output of above line is a list, but I need a numpy array. I could convert the output list of this command to a numpy array by `numpy.asarray(member_areas)`

Comment: Happy to help :)